# Where should I save a root certificate in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, trusted-root-certificates

I think I have uninstalled a programme in error and now get certificate errors whenever I try to visit a website (such as google) on the laptop.

I have researched and it appears I need to download a root certificate update but when I go to the Microsoft download site it asks me where I want to save the file to - does this matter? I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's simply asking you where to download it. It's a file and you have to save it somewhere, just like you would if you were downloading an image or a document.

After downloading a certificate you have to double-click it and follow instructions to install it.

If you're getting certificate errors, make sure your time and date are set correctly. That's the most common reason of those errors.

Comment: Ha now I feel stupid! Done that but now when I try and run it nothing happens. The date and time are correct.